# Rotate static text 45 degrees

Tags: text, rotation, andengine

I am trying to set a single line of static text so it lies across the secreen at 45 degrees.
This is my code but it has no effect.

```
mLoser = new Text(20, 430, mFont36,"Game Over!  No more moves.",  getVertexBufferObjectManager());
mLoser.setPosition(400 - mLoser.getWidth()/2, 480 - mLoser.getHeight()-2);
mLoser.setRotationCenter(mLoser.getX(), mLoser.getY());
mLoser.setRotation((float) -0.125);
mLoser.setVisible(false);
mMainScene.attachChild(mLoser);
```

I have my game working and just trying a few ideas I haven't used before.
Could you explain how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**
I just had to set the rotation to -45 instead of -0.125. Doh!
A bit more fiddling with the positioning and got what I wanted.